# Using datepickers to filter datagrid

Tags: mysql, wpf, date, datagrid, datepicker

Please help me, I have been stuck on this all day!!

I am wanting to filter results of wpf datagrid using two datepickers. Mysql query i have so far is as follows

Code:

```
MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(connectionSQL);
cs.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from Transactions WHERE date BETWEEN '"+datePicker1.Text +"' AND '"+datePicker2.Text +"' ", cs);

MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);

da.Fill(ds);

this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

My code has no errors but the dataset returns as empty even though I have got records which correspond to query.

Does datepicker require any binding in xaml? DBase date field has type of date. and saves dates with this format 2013-03-11

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the field `date` is of type DATE, then it may be worth just throwing in a DATE() around the arguments in case your connector is doing something odd.  This feels like a long shot though. Example as follows

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE date BETWEEN DATE('"+datePicker1.Text +"') AND DATE('"+datePicker2.Text +"') ", cs);
```

If this does not help at all, please update your question with the Transactions table structure and some example data that you are expecting to match.

On an editorial note, SELECT and FROM are usually capitalised.